# How to make multithread my communication code between Raspberry Pis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading

Im trying to communicate two RPi with TCP. One RPi is server and other is client. Server part includes motor and sensor, client part includes joystick. I want to send control values from client to the server, and sensor values from server to the client. My code can do these separately, i can control BLDC from server to the client and send sensor values from client to the server. But i am trying to do these at the same time. How can i do that?

Server code:

```
import socket
import os
import time
os.system("sudo pigpiod")
time.sleep(1)
import pigpio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pi = pigpio.pi()
ESC = 4
min_value = 1200
max_value = 2400
HOST = '' 
PORT = 65458
a = 0
c = 0
def control():
  data = conn.recv(1024)
  stringdata = data.decode('ascii')
  altan = int(stringdata)
  alta = altan + 1000
  print(alta)
  pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, alta)
def update():
  global a
  global c
  a = a + 5
  c = c + 3
def sendsensorvalues():
  b = 'd1' + str(a)
  conn.send(b.encode('ascii'))
  d = 'd2' + str(c)
  conn.send(d.encode('ascii'))
  update()
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  s.bind((HOST, PORT))
  s.listen()
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  with conn:
    print('CONNECTED BY', addr)
    while True:
        control()
        sendsensorvalues()
```

Client code :

```
import socket
import serial
from time import sleep
HOST = '169.254.78.190'
PORT = 65458
def sendmotor():
  read = ser.readline()
  a = int(read)
  b = str(a)
  s.sendall(b.encode('ascii'))

def displayfirst():
  a = strdata[2:]
  print('First senso value is : ' + a)
def displaysecond():
  b = strdata[2:]
  print('Second sensor value is : ' + b)
def getsensorvalues():
  data = s.recv(1024)
  strdata = data.decode('ascii')
  if strdata[1] == '1':
    displayfirst()
  else:
    displaysecond()


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  s.connect((HOST, PORT))
  ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600)
  ser.baudrate = 57600
  while True:
    sendmotor()
    getsensorvalues()
```

When i run this codes, i get errors:

[Server part error, control() function takes two value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/525IW.jpg)

[Client part error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrYfL.jpg)

Comment: Altan, please copy the traceback texts and paste them into the question instead of adding links to pictures.

Comment: i will, this is my first time in stackoverflow (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server part error

The server receives up to 1024 bytes at once with `data = conn.recv(1024)`. From the screen image it is obvious that the data items sent were `516` and that two consecutive items `516516` were received at once, causing the error when interpreted as one large number. One way to fix this is to not send data of variable length, but rather of fixed length and receive only that number of bytes, e. g. with [`import struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) and in the client changing

```
  b = str(a)
  s.sendall(b.encode('ascii'))
```

to

```
  b = struct.pack('i', a) # length 4
  s.sendall(b)
```

as well as in the server changing

```
  data = conn.recv(1024)
  stringdata = data.decode('ascii')
  altan = int(stringdata)
```

to

```
  data = conn.recv(4)
  altan = struct.unpack('i', data)[0]
```

Client part error

The shown client error is likely a consequence of `strdata` being empty due to the termination of the server. Besides that, the client has the same problem as the server with potentially receiving concatenated sensor values, which you can address in a similar way, e. g. by changing

```
  b = 'd1' + str(a)
  conn.send(b.encode('ascii'))
```

to

```
  conn.send(struct.pack('=2si', b'd1', a))    # length 6
```

…

Comment: thanks man, your code is solution for errors but now i have update error. client sends joysytick values to the server but this value is always 1555(default value). i moved joysytick but value doesnt update always printing 1555.

Comment: If the value in the client already before sending is always the same, this is something quite different from _communication code between Raspberry Pis_, so you'd have to post a new question. (But your _Server part_ image showed a value of 1516, not 1555 - how's that?)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do I/O multiplexing on UNIX is to use `select`. Python has a standard binding for it, the [`select` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html).
However, this is pretty low-level.

If you are using Python 3.4 or later, I would advise you to use the [`selectors` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) instead. The example at the bottom of that page should help get you started.

**Edit**: [this guide](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) might also come in handy. It contains sample code and explanations.